# Gayatri mantra and three Lokas (planes)

Tags: vedas, lokas, gayatri-mantra

Gayatri mantra starts with "*Oṃ bhūr bhuvaḥ svaḥ*". It praises god Savitr (Sun God) for illuminating worlds Bhu (Earth), Bhuva, Svah (Svarga).

We all know that , there are seven lokas above earth as enumerated below :-

1. Bhu (Our Earth)
2. Bhuva
3. Svah (Svarga/Heaven)
4. Mahar Loka
5. Jana Loka
6. Tapa Loka
7. Satya Loka (Abode of Brahma)

Why Sun god just illuminates only three upper lokas(planes)? Why didn't they mention other Lokas?

I completely understand, there can be different interpretations for the very same words. For example, [they translate](http://gayatri.awgp.org/ImportanceofGayatri/TheMeaningofGayatriMantra/) Bhu, Bhuvah and Svah as :-

- Bhu - Embodiment of Vital Spiritual Energy (Pran)
- Bhuvah - Destroyer of Sufferings
- Svah - Embodiment of Happiness

But Vedas contains multiple layers for very same words, I believe there is something in first interpretation too.

Comment: there is also another interpretation that bhu, bhuva and svah refer to the three planes of existence i.e. GROSS/PHYSICAL PLANE (stula sarira), ASTRAL PLANE (linga/sukshma sarira) and CAUSAL PLANE (karana sarira) and savittr refers to 'Glowing One' or 'Brilliant One' or 'Being of Intense Light'. Thus the mantra can be translated as 'Om - the Brilliant One who is the substrate of the three worlds/planes, we meditate on Thy form for it is Thee who illumines the Intellect'. Thus according to this interpretation God (not necessarily Sun God but God in general) illumines all worlds!

Comment: Wiki article for the three planes of existence or the three bodies http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Bodies_Doctrine_%28Vedanta%29

Comment: There actually is an expanded version of the Gayatri Mantra that includes the other Lokas you mentioned.  It is during Sandhyavandanam while doing Pranayamam; see this excerpt from the Garuda Purana, after the word "Astra": http://gdurl.com/QMgB Another name for the Gayatri mantra is the Savitri mantra, so this expanded one is often called the Mahasavitri mantra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I got the answer to my old question. Here is quote from Bhagavata ([5.20.37](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/20/37))

> By the supreme will of Krishna, the mountain known as Lokāloka has
>   been installed as the outer border of the three worlds—Bhūrloka,
>   Bhuvarloka and Svarloka—to control the rays of the sun throughout the
>   universe.
>
> All the luminaries, from the sun up to Dhruvaloka, distribute their
>   rays throughout the three worlds, but only within the boundary formed
>   by this mountain. Because it is extremely high, extending even higher
>   than Dhruvaloka, it blocks the rays of the luminaries, which therefore
>   can never extend beyond it.

So it is very clear. Sun rays goes only upto svarga loka. Lokaloka mountain blocks the sun rays from going up further.

Gayatri mantra is very right in mentioning only earth,bhuvar,svarga loka as lokas sun rays would reach.

Comment: Svarga Loka is a different planteray system, i.e, a different galaxy whereas Sun is in Milky way so there is no way Sun rays could reach other galaxies.

Comment: All these lokas are not in physical dimension. If you look at the description of all these lokas , there is no way we can match the attributes in anything in physical, may be in other galaxies  or in milky way.

Comment: Property of matter would not change depending  on where we are there. I believe these lokas are in other dimension near our earth.

Comment: Srimad Bhagavatam gives the position of these lokas in yojanas, i.e, X is situated Y yojanas above or below. The description given in SB clearly refers to actual position of the different planets. Lokas are not in different dimension but the beings living there are! We can reach those lokas with spaceships but we cannot see the people living there.

Comment: Distance are between planes  (like bhumandala) not the physical bodies like earth , mars etc. Mahabharata has mentioned how arjuna travelled in the chariot of mathali to svargaloka, If they would be traveling  in  physical dimension , arjuna would have suffocated to death , the moment he left the stratosphere.

Comment: More over if you look into bhagavatam , it clearly mentions the inner width of brahmanda , which would extend just over Uranus. It also talks about sheaths surrounding the brahmanda which is 10 time larger than total width. Even if we do calculations of different sheaths it would not extend beyond nearby stars

Comment: It is the very brahmanda All these lokas and meru mountain lies. Some part of meru mountain can be found in himalayas but it extends below and above .

Comment: The Taittiriya Shakha (I forgot in which text), mentions all the Lokas you have told. It's found in the Krishna Yajur Veda Sandhyavandana.

Answer (score 0):

The Gayatri mantra is Rig Veda III. lxii. 10. It is also covered in Brihadaranyaka Upanishad V. xiv. 1. and VI. iii. 6.

Bhuh, Bhuvah, Svah (earth, sky, heaven) are called the Vyahritis. They are three syllables. According to the Brihadaranyaka U. (V. xiv. 1.)  - "The words Bhumi (earth), Antariksha (sky), and Dyaus (heaven) form eight syllables, and the first foot of the Gayatri consists of eight syllables. So the three worlds constitute the first foot of the Gayatri. Whosoever knows this about the [first] foot of the Gayatri wins all that is in the three worlds."

Although there are several lokas or heavens, the heavens referred to in the Gayatri is inclusive of all the heavens.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of why the Gayatri mantra only mentions those three Lokas and not others.

Comment: Asking 'why' to scripture is pointless. Scripture is scripture. Realize God and ask Him directly. Otherwise any question as to 'why' is bound by space, time, and causation.

Comment: OK, but whether it's pointless or not, that's what the OP is asking.  He's trying to find out whether it only illuminates those three Lokas or whether it illuminates other Lokas as well, and if so why it wouldn't mention those other Lokas.  If you think that question is pointless, then you should vote to close it.  But as it stands now, your answer doesn't address the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

In sanskrit body means kosha. and world means loka.

Like onion the self(ego) has various layers or body (kosha). and each body has related world called LOKA.

The phisical body is called annamay kosha and it also involves energy body. pranmay kosha .

The mental body is called manomay kosher. which includes your conscious, sub conscious and unconscious mind.

The causal body which is experiencing joy and sorrow is called vigyan may kosha.

The physical body sees the world around by 5 senses and its called bhu loka. referring life on earth, solar system etc.

the mental body sees the world around by perceiving the 5 senses as well as thoughts, and karmic bonds its bhuv loka.

the intellect body see the world around by perceiving intuitions and its called sva loka. referring angles and dcvill.

Thus bhur bhuv and svah are 3 lokas or triloka out of of the 14 lokas..

For More detail explaination please refer my video .
https://youtu.be/eWCXqnfiy6Q

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. You should cite some sources. Visit [help]. Also note that promoting youtube channel isn't supported here. You're linking your the same video you've advertised in your previous answer (which has been deleted as not an answer). Self-promotion can be considered as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Been puzzled with this question for quite a while. The answer you gave to yourself is not correct: The "Sun" in the Gayatri mantra is not the literal sun but it indicates "Light" as the divine knowledge.

Anyway, the answer to your question is that the three lokas mentioned in the mantra actually stand for all the 14 lokas. I will quote here from Arthur Avalon (Sir John Woodroffe)'s "*The Garland of Letters*":

> Then follow the three Vyāhṛtis—Bhūh, Bhuvah, Svah,  which are
> Lakṣaṇa of, that is, stand for, all the fourteen  Lokas, though now
> in the (Vyāvahārika) world we are only  concerned  with  the  first
> three;  Bhūh  for  Bhūh  and  the  seven nether Talas, Bhuvah for
> itself, and Svah for Svah  and the remaining upper regions up to
> Satya.

As you probably know there are not just the 7 (upper) lokas you mentioned but also the 7 lower ones. And the Gayatri mantra refers to all 14 of them in this way: Bhuh represents both the Earth and all the 7 lokas below it, Bhuvah represents only Bhuvah, and Svah represents both Svah and all the 4 remaining lokas above it.

And the reason that the mantra condenses all 14 lokas into 3 is that in our ordinary lives we are only concerned with those 3 lokas.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is found in proper analysis of Gayathri Mantra.

Gayathri Mantra contains the seed of everything around and within us.

We all know of Gayathri Devi as source of Gayathri Mantra. But not many know of Vishwakarma, the male counterpart of Gayathri Devi. It appears the current teachings/teachers of today have omitted this other half required to complete the Gayathri Mantra.

Vishwakarma here is not the shilpy which is what you will get by google search. Vishwakarma here is the Brahman.

The gayathri mantra we know today is just the most basic (kindergarten) meter (akshara).

Akshara means algebra :)

Om Bhur Bhuvah Svah is not Gayathri. 
It is kavach.

Tat Savitur Varenyam
Bhargo Devasya Dheemahi
Deeyo yona prachodayat .. is Gayathri

Gayathri Devi is energy. Vishwakarma Brahma is structure. Knowing how to channel energy is how you and me are here breathing. The lokas (worlds) you refer to is not what it is meant to be; forgivable blunder.

Pick up any (Shruti) text, loka is not refered to as planets which we all have come to understand. The correct sanskrit word is Patala. Patalas that are off spring from Vishwakarma Brahma are called Nakshatra.
So what is the meaning of Loka? The closest english word is "consciousness".

Western science do not accept the concept of consciousness. It is a para-science known as psychology. Until Jung lobbied for his research, the best cure for a mentally unstable person was lobotomy ( a surgical procedure of removing a part of your brain to cut off all sensory perception). This was the "science" that was practiced till 1980's.

"Consciousness" in sanskritic-meaning-english-reverse-translation would mean "Aura".

Aura is the energy field that is on the external of the body functioning as a cover (Kavach). The etymology of the english word "Cover" is a loan from the sanskrit word "Kavach".

How does Aura come about? It is emitted from the respective Chakras ( also refuted by western science)

How to emit Aura from Chakras? Through Gayatri Mantra upasana.

So, lokas means aura that is manifested from the chakras.

There are countless galaxies and universes mentioned in scriptures (Shruti), which today proved true, so Gayathri Mantra's reference is definitely not just about 7 planets. Also there are 9 planets that has effect on the human body according to Jyotish, one of the Vedanga.

So the above pointers further negates any remote reference that Gayathri Mantras reference of lokas means planets.

What it means is the 7 layers of aura which is being broadcasted  from the sahasra chakra in harmony with the rest of the chakras. The surya namaskar is an activator of the pineal glad which produces ojas of which you put into vibratory motion in sandhyavandhan using Gayathri.

By the way, one anga of Gayathri Mantra upasana is Suryanamaskar. This is the Surya reference that the Gayatri Mantra gives. The Surya that is an activator of the ojas.

So just because it mentions Surya, one cannot conclude that the rest of the sloka would double-mean references to planets.

Western science has understood this recently, embraced rather, and have built the Particle Accelerator (CERN), where a matter (atom) is excited by energy (Surya for the human body) and let to exhaust itself by "dancing" around a given trajectory [chakras (lokas) in human body] and then to fuse itself in the process with electrons (ojas with Gayatri Mantra) so as to produce anti-matter ( Shakti ~ Gayatri Mata )

Of course CERN is unsuccessful, as no mantra (vibration) in certain fixed patterns (algebra) was used. While every initiated Hindu goes through this cycle every morning in Suryanamaskar followed by Sandhyavandan.

Thus, matter is Gayatri Devi and anti matter is Vishwakarma Brahma; proven millenias ago. This is the upadesh that is revealed in Gayatri Vidya by a proper Guru ( a handful exist).

This truth is further embodied in the Sri Chakra, the physical manifestation of the Gayathri. When it is manifested in 3 dimensional as the Meru, it is completed as perfect, as the 7 layers of "loka", consciousness is establised.

The white man Macaulfie is responsible for this mistranslation of loka to patala, from which all current modern literature on this subject has been based on. He linked bharata-vasara to bhu loka. This science is taught in Srimad Bhagavatam by Sri Vishwakarma's son to Brihaspati.

Further proof: in the sankalpa stanza one can find "bharata vasara" mentioned. This is the correct patala (i.e. Earth). The names of the rest of the patalas can be found in the same Srimad Bhagavatam.

To gain deeper understanding how Gayathri is manifested, one has to seek Purusha Suktam [i.e. the vigyan (science) of cause: creation, preservation and destruction]

Advancing into the subject; there are 11 akshara variations. The secret starts off with the first akshara seque.

Comment: Are you saying that there's a Vishwakarma mantra that completes the Gayatri mantra, and which mentions the other Lokas?

Comment: Not a random Vishwakarma mantra, but the proper sequence which the Gayathri Mantra itself that has to be deciphered ..

Comment: Just because someone downvotes your post doesn't mean you need to delete it.  In any case, answers on this site should be backed up with sources (preferably scripture), so you should cite references that confirm your claims.  And also, you should avoid scientific speculation, since that is off-topic for the site.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. What vigyan our rishis expounded is written here. However, there are certain principles (tattwas) that can never be cited. As a Hindu, we need to know our scriptures are found as Shruti form and Smritis form. Gayatri Upasana is purely Smriti. Shruti is written vigyan (science) i.e. Puranas, Vedanta. Smriti is unwritten. That is why traditionally Gayatri Vidya or Savitri Vidya was taught in Gurukul in strict oral instructions through rishi (scientists) lineages. Why? The knowledge is dangerous in crooked hands. Imagine the spark stone in transformers movie.

Comment: However, commentaries (Shruti) are there by relevant Acharyas i.e Adi Sankara, Ramanuja, Madwacharya on this subject. Same as what I wrote above is found in their commentaries also. But you will never find Gayatri Vidya or Savitri Vidya text, as it is never meant to be a text in the first place, as it is Smriti. We Hindus have lost alot of ability to gain knowledge because of our western mentality of only seeking sources (Shruti). Hindu dharma has Shruti and Smriti. Time to re-gain Smriti consciousness.

Comment: But there are certain Smriti anga of Gayatri Vidya and Savitri Vidya revealed in Devi Mahatmayam i.e the discource Shakti gives to Aghora Brahma (Shiva) out of compassion. From this tranmutation of Smriti to Shruti is the start point of the Shiv Ling tattwa, which is in essence Sri Vidya ( the powerful logic and formulas behind Gayatri Mantra) . This is the closest one can get in Shruti (text)

Comment: Scientific speculation? I beg you to read the Shruti sources which I have mentioned in my posts here. It will be a great revelation. Btw, CERN (largest man-made particle accelerator) has accepted this Vigyan and have installed Natataja on their grounds ( the Shruti manifestation of Smriti that was revealed in Devi Mahatmayam). Hope it is scientific enough since CERN is a white guy's turf.

Comment: Finally, even though there are exact chapters and stanzas which I can provide, it will be of no use. As all available text (Shruti) today are corrupted from their original prose and grammar, which leads to a classic confusion like this post ( i.e. lokas (wrongly called as planets) in Gayatri mantra. This great tragedy happened in Benaras Hindu University some century ago by Muller, Macaulfie, etc. Original text was translated into English and German and then into Hindi using Devanagiri script. So whatever text we have in hand are technically altered, except Srimad Bhagavatam that survived.

Comment: I understand I have drifted a mile away from the original question. But here in my comments are genuine concerns that need to be understood, which will then answer the question.

Comment: Rather than making so many edits to your post, why don't you just do everything in one edit?

Comment: You're misusing the words Shruti and Smriti.  Shruti means that which is heard and it refers to the mantras heard directly from the gods by rishis through meditation.  These were compiled by Vyasa into the Vedas.  Smriti means that which is remembered and refers to the human compositions of rishis, including the Puranas, and Mahabharata.  In any case, you should cite sources or else your answer may be deleted, because otherwise other people may not know whether your answer is correct or not.

Comment: And you should make your question more organized and remove stuff that doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Sir it is not a misuse. This explaination is "english minded". As there is no concept of unseen knowledge in the "english" cultural doctrine, such a loose translation is offered in google and available texts. The correct way of interpreting Shruti is - that which is synergised from Smriti. Smriti is - that which is not bound (anhad naad), the primodial sound. Here is a better read in case I am boring:                                                   http://www.idsa.in/issuebrief/ShrutiandSmriti_PKGautam_120213.html

Comment: How do I add Smriti as a source when Gayatri Mantra is Smriti? Hence I have already issued 3 Shruti sources: Srimad Bhagavatam, Devi Mahatmayam and Purusha Suktam. These texts in their entireity (start to end) talk about Gayatri Upasana and Mantra vigyan.

Comment: All the points in the Answer is an expansion of what the Question poster seeks to know. The fault of the translation from original Shrutis, the acceptance of the Gayathri concept by western scientists based on loka (aura energy); and not on mere loka ~ planets, the possible cause of the fault in translation with the reference of Surya, probably the white translator doing a self inclusion of other planets into the final translation as a consequence.... In order to answer the question and further clarify, these points have to be raised.

Comment: Maybe you ought to know Vyas was not the only rishi to complie (synergize Smriti to Shruti). And he does not accept Gayatri upasana (because he was from the fishermen clan, and he did not perform Yagnopaveeta to be a Dvija to get Gayatri upasana diksha ). That is why his shaka (teachings) is mainly puranic based (Shruti - Mahabharat, etc). And this caused a rift as his parampara only follow Shruti, hence Gayatri upasana is not important. Do remember there were Sapta Rishis who all gave various Shrutis forms. Just for your additional knowledge.

Comment: Moreover according to Dharmasashtra, Shrutis are not simply made by men/rishis. Those are called Puranas and Ithihaas. To be precise: Each Veda is created from the face of Sadyojata Brahma, Vamadeva Brahma, Aghora Brahma, Tatpurusha Brahma and Isana Brahma. The last Veda is Pranava Veda. And subsequently each offspring (Param Rishi Parampara) of the 5 Brahmas added more sutras into the Vedas through Smriti. This is the correct creation of Vedas. Proof? Purusha Suktam.